# Is there a way to make latex ignore case sensitivity in its algorithmic package?

Tags: report, algorithmic, multiple-files

I am writing a report which constitutes separately prepared documents. Unfortunately almost all the documents have algorithms written in different formats like \WHILE and \While . I am having an issue where I need to change each algorithm in some of the documents because i need to compile them together.

Is there a way to make latex ignore the differences in case?

An example code:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\include{document1}
\include{document2}

\end{document}
```

document1.tex

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\WHILE{A}
\STATE Do Something
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

document2.tex

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\While{A}
\State Do Something
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the syntax if for `algorithmic`. If the commands' syntax is the same, you can do

```
\newcommand{\WHILE}{\While}
```

and similarly for the other commands.

Note that spaces are not ignored in arguments and that `\State` takes no argument in braces.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\WHILE}{\While}
\newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\EndWhile}
\newcommand{\STATE}{\State}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\WHILE{A}
\STATE Do Something
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\While{A}
\State Do Something
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Filling up the list of commands to define shouldn't take long.

Just for fun, some commands to capitalize an entire list; an `*` at the beginning means we also want the associated `\END...` command.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CAPITALIZE}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \hope_capitalize:w ##1 \q_stop }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \hope_capitalize:w
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF { * }
   { \__hope_capitalize_end:w }
   { \__hope_capitalize_single:w }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__hope_capitalize_single:w #1 \q_stop
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cc { \str_uppercase:n { #1 } } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__hope_capitalize_end:w #1 \q_stop
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cc { \str_uppercase:n { #1 } } { #1 }
  \cs_set_eq:cc { \str_uppercase:n { END#1 } } { End#1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\CAPITALIZE{*While,State}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\WHILE{ A}
\STATE Do Something
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\While{A}
\State Do Something
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The braces in the \STATE line and the spaces in the \WHILE line are typo errors; I have corrected them. The same error shows after using your solution. BTW I put the newcommands on the main tex file where I included paths for the separate documents. I am not good with latex so I am stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: I also have separated the example algorithms to clearly show my problem.